# How can I launch my Angular 5 web application with maven?

Tags: java, node.js, spring, angular, maven

1.) I started with a spring boot/maven project.

2.) I added Angular 5 files into the project.

3.) I tested that I could build the project via the command line using node, bower, and gulp.

Currently in my pom.xml I am importing the following:

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-node-and-npm</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v8.9.1</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>5.5.1</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>bower install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bower</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>gulp build</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>gulp</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <NODE_ENV>prod</NODE_ENV>
                        </environmentVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

-After I build my application using 'mvn package install', the build is successful. However my application is not running.

QUESTION: How do I see my application? Do I need to configure something else or add something else to my pom.xml?

Comment: I think during development you run your angular app and web app separately, once angular project is done, you build your angular project and copy build result to web app resources folder. To run your angular app in console go to your project and use command `ng serve` to start it.

Comment: How do I build my angular project and copy the build result to the web app resources folder? Meaning how do I link the two?

Comment: what worked for me and for others in nodejs and IIS is that you have your backend project in the root directory and angular in a subdirectory. And you have a `GET` `/` to serve the static `index.html` file that is located under the `dist`. In that case I could run my server locally and my angular app with hot reload

Comment: I believe the command to build it is `ng build`, this will product a new folder. The result from `ng build` is static javascript, css and html files, which you need to copy to your webapp. So these files are then accessible from the browser when accessing your boot app in browser.

Comment: Also to make clear, when developing your angular app you don't need to do the above setup each time you make changes. `ng serve` will run angular (node.js) web server and you can view your changes from this server.

Comment: learn this one : https://www.udemy.com/angular-4-java-developers/learn/v4/overview   or use Jhipster

Answer (score 0):

In this video, I was showing how to deploy an Angular app under the Spring Boot server: https://youtu.be/k8r76d8QzXs?t=2237.

Each time the Angular app changes, just re-run the npm run build command to deploy the new version of Angular bundles under the Spring Server.